# bool data type not visible in datatables csv export

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I am working with MVC3 and am using datatables for my grid. I have a table with data containing datatype bool. It is showing in my table but while exporting to Excel it is not visible.

Datatable code

```
"oTableTools": {
                   "aButtons": [
                       "xls",
                       "print"],
                   "sSwfPath": "../../Content/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

Comment: Please post the code that is exporting to Excel. Without a code sample, there's really nothing that can be done to help. Also explain what you mean by "it is not visible".

Comment: Generally for bool datatype, data will show as checkbox. But it is not showing in excel sheet after exporting.

Comment: Umm Sanjay... that code snippet looks like Flash... did you create copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf or...?